# Text show when auto typing text complete after add class other section

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to after text type active class on `.first` and remove and after deleting text and auto-typing is working fine.

The issue other `div` with `active` class add I want to show div when after type text and pause one second then active other div.

This is a very critical situation for me.

Please help I have super tried thanks in advance.
[image]

```js
Node.prototype.nextNode = function() {
  var cur = this;
  while (cur = cur.nextSibling) {
    if (cur.nodeType === 1 && !cur.classList.contains('fakeContent')) {
      return cur;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

Node.prototype.firstNode = function() {
  var cur = this.firstChild;
  if (cur.nodeType === 0) {
    return cur;
  } else {
    return cur.nextNode();
  }
};

Element.prototype.typeAndDelete = function(options) {
  options = options || {};

  var contentList = this,
    curContent = contentList.getElementsByClassName('active')[0] || contentList.firstNode();

  // default options
  var selectTimePerWord = options.selectTimePerWord || 100,

    typeTimePerWord = options.typeTimePerWord || 150,
    delayAfterSelect = options.delayAfterSelect || 500,
    delayAfterDelete = options.delayAfterDelete || 600,
    delayBetweenWords = options.delayBetweenWords || 1000;

  // create fake content
  var fakeContent = contentList.getElementsByClassName('fakeContent')[0];
  if (!fakeContent) {
    fakeContent = document.createElement('span');
    fakeContent.classList.add('fakeContent');
    fakeContent.classList.add('selecting');
    contentList.appendChild(fakeContent);
  }

  // selecting handler
  var selecting = function() {
    // initial fake content with the same text
    fakeContent.innerHTML = curContent.innerHTML;

    // start selecting
    var selectingAnimation = setInterval(function() {
      fakeContent.innerHTML = fakeContent.innerHTML.substring(0, fakeContent.innerHTML.length - 1);
      if (fakeContent.innerHTML.length <= 0) {
        clearInterval(selectingAnimation);

        deleting();
      }
    }, selectTimePerWord);
  };

  // deleting handler
  var deleting = function() {
    // delay, delete, and switch to the next content
    setTimeout(function() {
      fakeContent.classList.remove('selecting');
      fakeContent.classList.add('typing');
      curContent.classList.remove('active');

      curContent = curContent.nextNode() ? curContent.nextNode() : contentList.firstNode();
      curContent.classList.add('typing');
      curContent.classList.add('active');
    }, delayAfterSelect);

    // delay and start typing
    setTimeout(function() {
      typing();
    }, delayAfterDelete);
  };

  // typing handler
  var typing = function() {
    // delete fake content
    fakeContent.innerHTML = "";

    // start typing
    var typingAnimation = setInterval(function() {
      fakeContent.innerHTML = curContent.innerHTML.substring(0, fakeContent.innerHTML.length + 1);

      // stop typing
      if (fakeContent.innerHTML.length >= curContent.innerHTML.length) {
        fakeContent.classList.remove('typing');
        clearInterval(typingAnimation);

        // delay between words
        setTimeout(function() {
          curContent.classList.remove('typing');
          fakeContent.classList.add('selecting');
          selecting();
        }, delayBetweenWords);
      }
    }, typeTimePerWord);
  };

  return selecting();
};

document.getElementById('content').typeAndDelete({
  delayAfterDelete: 500
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}

@-moz-keyframes blinkCursor {
  0% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid transparent;
  }
  51% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid #999;
  }
  100% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid #999;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinkCursor {
  0% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid transparent;
  }
  51% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid #999;
  }
  100% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid #999;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkCursor {
  0% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid transparent;
  }
  51% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid #999;
  }
  100% {
    border-left: 0.1em solid #999;
  }
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#content li {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100%;
}

#content li.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

#content li.active.typing {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

#content .fakeContent {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 1em;
}

#content .fakeContent:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1em;
  left: calc(100% - 0.1em);
  top: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  border-left: 0.1em solid #999;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -o-background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-animation: blinkCursor 1.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blinkCursor 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: blinkCursor 1.5s linear infinite;
}

#content .fakeContent.typing:after {
  background-color: transparent;
  -moz-animation: none;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  animation: none;
  left: 100%;
}

#content .fakeContent.selecting:after {
  -moz-animation: none;
  -webkit-animation: none;
  animation: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>I am a
  <span id="content">
        <li >Developer</li>
        <li>Programmer </li> 
        <li>Problem Solver</li>
        <li>Sprouter!</li>
        <li>Sprouter!</li>
        <li>Sprouter!</li>
        <li>Sprouter!</li>
    </span>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="first">
      There
    </div>
    <div class="first">
      There
    </div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I truly want to help you but I don't fully understand the question. Please try to rephrase it, add punctuation etc. Also, and more important, try to create a gif image with the result you want to achieve. It will much easier to understand if we could actually see the result.

Comment: Thanks for the show interest to resolve my problem, When the first-line typing completed then add class main inner div > '.first', I hope now you understand. look like li sibling.

Comment: I have update image in the question. The example just Look Like not same: https://stripe.com/about

Comment: The image you supplied is not similar to the result of the code you supplied. Do you want to add a class `.active` to the first element with the class `first` when the autotype process is finished? Do you want it for each cycle of typing or only the first one?

Comment: the same condition I have fixed in the codepen URL: https://codepen.io/tushar-kumawat/pen/MZOmxw
but now one more issue I want active class to add look like li

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/XozzEe?editors=1000

Comment: Yes exactly right thank you much I really appreciate for your effort.

Comment: Sure :) My pleasure. Are you understand the change in the code?

Comment: Yup, please share your LinkedIn account if you don't mind? and also can you please convert the answer so I can do right mark of the answer.

Comment: It's just in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/863110/mosh-feu?tab=profile) page :)

Comment: Okay again thank you so much :)

Comment: @MoshFeu I need your help now explain first typing is fine and for start selecting delete to remove class this not fine just I wanna to the whole line select and then remove the active class.